# Currying numpy's ndarray type

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray, type-hinting

Numpy just released support for typing in 1.22.0. The `ndarray` class accepts two params: shape and data type. I would like to wrap the `ndarray` and only require the data type to specified. Is there a way to do this?

```py
from typing import Generic, TypeVar, Any
import numpy as np


T = TypeVar('T')
class NDArrayAnyShape(np.ndarray[Any, Generic[T]]):
    ...

NDArrayAnyShapeIntDtype = NDArrayAnyShape[int]
```

This throws

```
TypeError: Too few arguments for NDArrayAnyShape
```